# Does Xubuntu run well on a good PC? or should i stick with Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

Does Xubuntu give a speed increase compared to Ubuntu on a good PC?
Or is there no difference when running on a good CPU? (6700HQ)

And if yes, Xubuntu IS faster.. why is that? less programs come with Xubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: 'well' is a matter of opinion. xubuntu uses software that have less of a memory footprint but that also means less features. What you want is up to you. Ubuntu is free of charge. So is Xubuntu. Try them yourself and form your own opinion. And when you do ... you can always change your mind. Or have both at the same time. It is not like you have to pay 100s of euro or dollars before you can use it (like with some other operating systems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Xubuntu - I detest Unity & prefer a lighter-weight interface, this does come with being less of a power-hog so yes, there is a tendency for better speed; however a good PC with adequate RAM is quite likely not to show a big difference, more time is spent waiting for network, drives, etc.

As Rinzwind says, try it & see - you can dual-boot or just have a choice of window managers at login, and you can (of course) add in as much bloatware as you choose later :) I tend to have a lot of smaller packages in mine which doesn't much affect running, until things with persistent servers get installed (eg `mysql`..).